# working with file offsets in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata

I'm trying to seek 1,000 bytes into a file handle and write it to an instance of NSData (or NSMutableData).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    int offset = 1000;
    NSFileHandle *fHandle;
    NSMutableData *data;
    fHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"bigtextfile.txt"];
    [fHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];

    data = [NSMutableData data];
    [fHandle writeData:data];
    [fHandle closeFile];
    [data length]; // this comes out to 0 bytes?
```

Comment: instead of  fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"bigtextfile.txt"]; use fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"bigtextfile.txt"]; for wride mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you trying to read data after seeking or want to write some thing there? -- you are opening file for reading then you are trying to write empty data.

If you want to read then using following line or similar API's not write

```
data = [fHandle availableData];
```

If you want to write then open the file for writing -- then have some content in NSData object and write it to the file.

Comment: I'm simply trying to set a pointer to an offset in the file using seek, and then write from that offset to the end of the file to an instance of NSData/NSMutableData.

Comment: "Writing to an instance of NSData" is actually called "reading." :-)

Comment: If you want to write then use "fileHandleForWritingAtPath" --- present code open the file in read mode you can not write.

Answer (score 1):

> write it to an instance of NSData

That's the basic problem right there. NSFileHandle's `-writeData:` method doesn't write *to* an instance of NSData. It writes *from* a data object *to* a file. So your code creates an empty data object, then tries to write it to a read-only file handle. It's not actually doing anything that would change the contents of the `data` object at all.

To *read* data *from* the file, you want to use either `-readDataToEndOfFile`, or `-readDataOfLength:`.